# Referencing two levels of ancestors from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Picture a model similar to GitHub or GitLab issues. There are three entities:

```
Project --- Milestones --- Issues
```

However, since an issue might not have a milestone associated just yet, issues also hold a reference to the project entity. In code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
  has_many :milestones

end

class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :issues

end

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :milestone

end
```

Is there a way to tell Rails that in any given issue the following must hold `self.milestone.project == self.project` ?

Also, is there a way to have the following work properly? `project.milestones.first.issues.new()` and have that newly created issue have the `project` reference properly populated?

Answer (score 0):

I would not add a project association to the Issue model.  Instead add a `has_many :issues, :through => :milestones` association to the `Project` model. Add a `delegates` directive on the `Issue` model so that you can access the project directly from an issue.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :milestones
  has_many :issues, :through => :milestones
end

class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :issues
end

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :milestone
  delegates :project, :to => :milestone
end
```

Given a product, find all of it's issues:

```
project = Project.find(1)
project.issues
```

Given a milestone, find all of it's issues:

```
milestone = Milestone.find(1)
milestone.issues
```

Given an issue, get it's project:

```
issue = Issue.find(1)
issue.project
```

Comment: Sounds good in theory, but you _can_ create an issue associated to a project, and only later set its milestone.